# How to sort a vector of vectors while keeping the original indexes?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array, stdvector

The code generates a variable sized matrice, whose column and row size is defined by the user. The user also manually fills in the first row, and then the other rows are automatically filled, each row after the first being the original row divided by the row we're on.

Now I wanted to find the `N` largest elements in said matrices, where **`N` being the number of rows**. When I print the array/matrice/vector that contains those `N` largest values, to **display alongside the value the element's index in the original matrices**.

What would be the best way of sorting this `2D` vector, while keeping its original indexes?

This probably seems really basic to you guys but I've been wrestling with it for a bit.

I've tried the sort function, and while I got it to work, it scrambles the indexes and alters the original matrices.

```
int main() 
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> header;
    vector<vector<double>> matrice;
    vector<double> temp;

    cout << "How many columns does it have?" << endl;
    cin >> columnsize;
    cout << "How many rows does it have?" << endl;
    cin >> rowsize;
    cout << "Whats the number of votos in order" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < columnsize; i++) 
    {
        cin >> ccontent;
        temp.push_back(ccontent);
    }
    matrice.push_back(temp);

    for (int i = 0; i < columnsize; i++) 
    {
        cout << "Qual é o nome da lista:" << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> Nomelista;
        header.push_back(Nomelista);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < rowsize; i++) 
    {
        temp.clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < columnsize; j++) 
        {
            temp.push_back((matrice[0][j]) / (i + 1));
        }
        matrice.push_back(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I've tried the sort function, and while I got it to work, it scrambles the indexes and alters the original matrice." please show that code. There seems to be nothing wrong with the code you posted, but from your text it is not 100% clear what is missing / what you want to do

Comment: see also here: [mcve]

Comment: Hey! Sorry, quite new here. I just wanted to sort the 2d vector, matrice, in the code I showed, so that it would display the n largest elements, n being the same number as the total number of rows in the matrice,  while showing the index of each of those largest elements, does that make sense?

I added the code mostly so you could see the vector I'm trying to sort.

Comment: @FilipeGomes To be honest, the question is not so clear. Do you want to get the largest element in the matrix and it's index, with sorting it. Is that correct? And what is `header` for?

Comment: @JeJo Sorry, I want the N largest elements in the matrix and their index, N is the number of rows the Matrix has. 

The header is for a different part of the program, it stores the names of the columns.

Comment: @FilipeGomes Please follow the advice to include a [mcve]. Cut away the parts not needed to solve the specific problem but include enough to make it compile.

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear on what you want, but the obvious answer seems to make a copy of the original, sort the copy and you have both the original and a copy. You can also simply store the max of each row in a separate vector (either before or after the sort depending on the order wanted)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That is what I understood in the beginning. See my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56434314/revisions). Later OP commented in the answer. He/she wants to sort the entire elements in the matrix in descending order and the first `N` elements and their corresponding indexes needed to be optioned. Where `N` is the no. of rows of the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean

```
N = matrice.size() = no. rows of the matrix!
```

the following should do the job, even though that might not be the best way.

- Provide a struct `ElementIntex`, where the *element* of the `matrix` and their *corresponding indexes* could be stored.
- Iterate through the elements in the `matrix` and store them into a vector of `ElementIntex`.
- Sort the `std::vector<ElementIntex>` according to the *element* in the struct `ElementIntex` using a binary predicate. (In descending order)
- Return the first `N` number of elements from this sorted `std::vector<ElementIntex>`, where `N` is equal to no. of rows in the `matrix`.

Following is an example code: **([See Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hxk3EWm4SzJpzCqw))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>   // std::size_t
#include <algorithm> // std::sort

struct ElementIntex
{
    std::size_t col, row;
    double element;
    ElementIntex(std::size_t cl, std::size_t rw, double ele)
        : col{cl}
        , row{rw}
        , element{ele}
    {}
};

std::vector<ElementIntex> getLargestElements(
                          const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrice)
{
    std::vector<ElementIntex> vec;
    // reserve the memory to prevent unwanted reallocations: if you now the size
    // vec.reserve(/*total no. of elements*/)
    std::size_t rowIndex = 0;
    for (const std::vector<double>& row : matrice)
    {
        std::size_t colIndex = 0;
        for (const double element : row)
            vec.emplace_back(rowIndex, colIndex++, element);
        ++rowIndex;
    }
    // sort descending order of elements in the vector of `ElementIntex`
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
            [](const auto & lhs, const auto & rhs) { return lhs.element > rhs.element; });
    // return N largest elements from the sorted vector: where N = matrice.size() = no. rows!
    return { vec.cbegin(), vec.cbegin() + matrice.size() };
}

int main()
{
    // consider the following vector of vectors(matrx in your case)
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrice{
        {1.05, -8.05, 1.0, 8.58, 3.04},
        {15.05, 8.05, 7.05, 8.58},
        {11.05, 88.05, 7.06},
        {-12.05, -8.05}
    };

    const auto resultVec{ getLargestElements(matrice) };
    for (const ElementIntex& elementIndex : resultVec)
        std::cout << "The element " << elementIndex.element
                  << " and index [" << elementIndex.row 
                  << "][" << elementIndex.col << "]\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
The element 88.05 and index [1][2]
The element 15.05 and index [0][1]
The element 11.05 and index [0][2]
The element 8.58 and index [3][0]
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much, how would I modify so it would give me the N biggest values of the whole matrice and not just of each row? 
I want to find the biggest value in the WHOLE matrice, N times, and those N times just correspond to the amount of rows, so I want to find largest value, then the second largest value, and so on, N times, not the largest value of each row, which is what this does.

Comment: What I mean is finding the largest values in the whole matrice, if the matrice had 2 rows, I would want to find the two largest values in the whole matrice, not the largest in each row.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -3):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> v;
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    //input: 1 5 3 6 8 7 9
    // n =7
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
    vector<int> temp1;
    int e;
    cin>>e;
    temp1.push_back(e);
    temp1.push_back(i);
    v.push_back(temp1);

    }

    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<v[i][0]<<" "<<v[i][1]<<endl;
    }

/* output: 
1 0
2 2
5 1
6 3
7 5
8 4
9 6*/
}
```

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`, really?

Comment: It's not a standard C++ header file. Use the appropriate header files for the classes/functions you use.

Comment: Well, your answer is supposed to serve people coming here with similar questions as OP. Your answer is dependent on a certain development environment and maybe even a certain version of that. You can of course answer what you want but spreading `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` by including it in a proposed solution is just plain wrong. If you do the job and include the correct files (and it answers the question) you may get an upvote instead.

Comment: You can use whatever you want. Nobody edited or removed your answer. But if you choose to use something bad, don't be surprised when you get down voted. That header is not portable and is a bad habit that has proven hard to eliminate from new programmers. It *is* bad.

Comment: Besides the problems with code shown, this answer is also incomplet. Please add a description of how this code fixes the problem or otherwise elaborate on the changes you've made.